# Are there any data load callback functions / events exposed in chartkick react?

Tags: reactjs, chartkick

From a brief look at the source, I think the answer is no.. but just in case - is something like this possible? or would I have to look at loading the data in myself?

```
<LineChart data="/data-uri" onData={(data) => console.log(data)}/>
                      this: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

A (possibly ill conceived) use-case:

```js
const MyChart = () => {
  const [total, setTotal] = React.useState("...");
  const calcTotal = data => {
    // ... do some calc
  };
  return (
    <>
      <h1>{total} Widgets</h1>
      <LineChart
        data="/data-uri"
        onData={data => {
          setTotal(calcTotal(data));
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Well It says that data can be a callback in the docs https://github.com/ankane/react-chartkick#data
But of course, it's not exposed as a prop on the component.Would that be helpful?

Comment: Perhaps ill-conceived, but my use-case would be to do something like display a summary (e.g. a total or count) based on the data retrieved. Have updated question to include an example.

Comment: It's simple enough to do the data-fetching myself, then work out the total and pass in the data to the chart component - just checking that the callback wasn't already there somewhere

Comment: Well since `data` prop could also be a function that has `success` and `fail` callback, can't you set your count there when you receive the data ?

Comment: yes - I would also have to fetch the data from the server myself in that case AFAIK.